# What is docker node:9-stretch?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I'm looking at a Dockefile we have in one of our projects that essentially builds our UI.

I see it's using `FROM node:9-stretch` which ships with npm 5.6.0. I want to use `npm ci` which requires 5.7.0 so i need to update my dockerfile node base image.

I do not see a node:9-stretch in docker hub https://hub.docker.com/_/node/

Where is this pulling node:9-stretch from and what is a `-stretch` version of a base image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The node 9 build was dropped after this commit https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/commit/b22fb6c84e3cac83309b083c973649b2bf6b092d. You can find Dockerfile in diff.

The node:9-stretch image you can pull build before the commit, and persisted in docker hub. The 9-stretch tag exists in Tags page, as for now https://hub.docker.com/_/node?tab=tags&page=18.

Comment: Awesome! Do you know what a `-stretch` image is though?

Comment: @Catfish `stretch` should refer to the Debian release version `9.x`: https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/